# How do i render html/css same in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i am making a menu for my school assignment and it needs to work in both IE and firefox.
I am done the menu and it works perfectly in firefox, but i am having trouble getting it to display properly in IE

A part can be found over here: http://tutudragon3.info/ie-trying.php

When i click the home image in firefox, a dropdown sort of thing pops-up with 2 images with text "d" and "d". In firefox, there is no space between those dropdown images, but when i try it in IE, I see a small blank space between them.

how could i fix this (delete that space) please. I tried many different things but it didn't work.

Using IE8 by the way.

Answer (score 5):

Before worrying about any specific bugs:

1. Use a Doctype that triggers standards mode, as quirks mode inconsistencies are a nightmare to deal with. If in doubt, use HTML 4.01 Strict: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html
2. Deal with [machine detectable errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftutudragon3.info%2Fie-trying.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 3):

If you have done the things David mentions, and still see some differences, you might want to take a look at [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), it is a JavaScript library to make Microsoft Internet Explorer behave like a standards-compliant browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any problem in IE7. But if you are having the problem, try giving `display:block;` to the `<A>` and `<IMG>` tags. The problem should vanish.